# How do I add additional JavaScript documentation to NetBeans?

Tags: javascript, netbeans

I would like to add the [Titanium JavaScript Documentation](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.8.1/api.json) to the NetBeans IDE.

If it is not possible to add in the JSON format at this link but other formats can be added, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible. Generally support for JavaScript libraries is not implemented. Workaround is to add some JS library file (.js not json) to your project so it will be scanned by NetBeans and code completion will work.

Comment: Hopefully the new support in NB 7.3 will add this capability :)